# Returning Future[Int] from Future[Option[Int]] with support of Failing the future

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-collections

I have the below block of code. My intent is to do some processing with the method params and return `Future[Int]` or `fail` the `Future`. I want to fail the `Future` if my argument to method inside the `Future` is of type `None`. I have the below code. I wonder if there is a much more concise and functional way to achieve the same.

```
def testoption(myFutOptInt: Future[Option[Int]]) = {
    myFutOptInt.map { myOptInt =>
      myOptInt match {
        case None => throw new BadRequestException("Oh no.....") //Future.failed(BadRequestException(""))
        case Some(myInt) => myInt + 45
      }
    } recoverWith {
      case e:Exception => Future.failed(e)
    }
  }
```

- I am not liking the part that I have to do a match, wondering if there is a way to do a `map` or something better and still achieve it. If I do `getOrElse` I guess I won't be able to write the business logic if the value is not `None`? So `getOrElse` is not possible either I think?
- The other thing I do not like about this code is that I am throwing an exception and then I have to do `recoverWith` to fail the `Future`.

I can enhance the above code how?

Answer (score 3):

If you need specifically `BadRequestException`, this is enough:

```
def testoption(myFutOptInt: Future[Option[Int]]) =
  myFutOptInt.map { 
    case None => throw new BadRequestException("Oh no.....") 
    case Some(myInt) => myInt + 45
  }
```

And if you don't care about particular error type, you can cut it even more:

```
def testoption(myFutOptInt: Future[Option[Int]]) = myFutOptInt.map(_.get + 45)
```

This will give you `java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get` if there's no value

---

`recoverWith` is absolutely redundant b/c if an exception is thrown inside a `map`, whole operation results in a failed `Future`. This is true for most, if not all, `Future` methods.

For match, you can avoid it using `opt.fold(throw ...)(...)` or `.map(...).getOrElse(throw ...)`, but I'd argue those options are less readable. I suggest just using pattern-matching function definition to reduce extra code

Comment: I am writing this method say for to be used as a service been and I want to return a Future.failed to the REST Controller. For that use case also, you would say that I can avoid using ``Future.failed and recoverWith``?

Comment: @curiousengineer the use case does not matter. If a function inside `map` throws, the resulting `Future` is failed automatically, and you don't need to do anything else. Your `recoverWith` code is essentially a no-op.

Comment: I think I get it. The whole point for recoverWith if not always at times would be to say if I get ``Exception of type so and so``, try to recover doing so and so. Here I am just failing the future anyways in recoverWith which as you say will  fail with throws. Right?

Comment: @curiousengineer yes. You're just always failing it again.